# Tensorial nature of four-acceleration

Tags: classical-electrodynamics

In classical electrodynamics, we define the four acceleration as
$$ b^\mu \equiv \dfrac{\text{d}u^\mu}{\text{d}\tau} = \dfrac{\text{d}^2 x^\mu}{\text{d}\tau^2}.$$
The scalar $b^2$ is equal to
$$ b^2 \equiv b^\mu b_\mu = \gamma^4(v) [\gamma^2(v) (\textbf{v}\cdot \textbf{a})^2 /c^2 +\textbf{a}^2 ] \geq 0.$$

> Why the scalar $b^2$ depends on the velocity $\textbf{v}$? Is the tensor transformation of $b^2$ right?

Cfr. for example: https://books.google.es/books?id=RfR2GawB-xcC&pg=PA137&dq=four-acceleration&hl=es&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjd9qPpr6DXAhXJWRQKHX4SDl0Q6AEIWzAH#v=onepage&q=four-acceleration&f=false